# GHCi is crashing when executed from a directory that has a Prelude.hs

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

GHCi crashes when I try to start it from my src directory because it has a Prelude.hs file.  I am not sure why this is happening though because I've set NoImplicitPrelude and I am doing a 'import "base" Prelude'

Here is my ghci.conf:

```
:set -XNoImplicitPrelude -XPackageImports

import "base" Prelude
```

Here is the GHCi output:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.

Top level:
    attempting to use module `Prelude' (./Prelude.hs) which is not loaded
```

Comment: Please include the output of GHCi when it crashes

Comment: It'd probably be helpful if you simplify the problem down to its smallest reproducible case -- i.e. remove all pragmas and imports except the ones which actually cause the error

Comment: I guess you have `-XPackageImports` set too? Otherwise, that import won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that GHCi is loading the Prelude package *before* even looking at your `.ghci` config. So you can fix the problem by running:

```
ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude
```

which you could alias to `ghci` in your shell.